# Unable to get the metadata for the document name contains(') using Rest Api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, document, metadata

Not able to get the metadata of a document contains file name with (') using rest api

```
http://site url/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('filepath')/?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double ('), write ('') instead of (')